# Bash script using output of mount as a variable throws numerous errors

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Ubuntu 18.04 server + LXDE. I can't get the hang of this bash scripting.
This is my script "start" (with line numbering):

```
#!/bin/bash
reply=sudo mount 192.168.0.2:/home/dk/NFS /home/dk/NFS
if $reply == 0
then 
    echo "NFS mounted OK"
else 
    echo "Mounting NFS failed: $reply"
fi

reply=sudo mount LABEL="60GB" /home/dk/60GB
if $reply == 0
then 
    echo "60GB mounted OK"
else 
    echo "Mounting 60GB failed: $reply"
fi
exit 0
```

This is the result of running it:

```
$ ./scripts/start
mount: only root can do that
./start: line 3: ==: command not found
Mounting NFS failed: 
mount: only root can do that
./start: line 11: ==: command not found
Mounting 60GB failed: 
$
```

- Why did it ignore the `sudo` before `mount`?
- Why did it not consider `if` to be a command ?
- Why did it not print the (non-zero) value of `$reply`?

Comment: If you’re writing this script to mount the two listed drives at startup, I’d recommend just putting them in /etc/fstab. You wouldn’t be able to get custom error messages, though.

Comment: You desperately need to read a tutorial on how to write shell scripts. You have lots of misunderstandings about the syntax. Paste your code into shellcheck.net to see how many problems it reports.

Comment: What @Barmar said.  If your approach to scripting is to type in some incantations and hope they do what you want, I'm sorry to have to tell you, you'll never [become an excellent programmer](https://www.codesimplicity.com/post/why-programmers-suck/) that way.

Answer (score 11):

Well you're assigning output of a command incorrectly. Should be:

```
reply=$(sudo mount 192.168.0.2:/home/dk/NFS /home/dk/NFS)
```

That's called command substitution. Sometimes you see it in old Bourne shell syntax with backquotes instead of `$(...)`, but that's not recommended nowadays because backquotes can't be nested easily, while you can do nested `$( cmd1 $(cmd2))`

> Why did it not consider "if" to be a command?

If statements operate on commands, but what you give is variable `$reply`, which only exists temporarily ( see later in the answer about that) so it exists only for `mount` command's environment, but the shell running the script knows nothing of it - it doesn't exist. To compare strings use `[`, and yes it's a command also known as `test`. So do

```
if test "$reply" == 0
```

See quotes? That's important, otherwise if there's spaces, shell will expand variable to two or more separate entities not one.

But if you want to check exit status of command, just do

```
if mount 192.168.0.2:/home/dk/NFS /home/dk/NFS
```

See no `sudo`? That's because it's usually redundant to use sudo in script multiple times. Just call script itself with sudo and all commands will have root privilege.

I'd also say echo is redundant because mount command already can print errors to terminal, but if you want custom message, you can do

```
if mount 192.168.0.2:/home/dk/NFS /home/dk/NFS 1> /dev/null
then
       echo "Success"
else
       echo "Fail"
fi
```

Because of `1>` normal output is suppressed (actually redirected to `/dev/null` especially for that purpose)  but errors will show if anything goes wrong.

> Why did it ignore the "sudo" before "mount" ?

As for why you're getting error message that's because the form

```
reply=sudo mount 192.168.0.2:/home/dk/NFS /home/dk/NFS
```

is treated as `envvariable=value command arg1 arg2`, i.e. you're putting variable `result` with value `sudo` into environment of `mount` command. The command will know about it, but after command exits - the variable is gone too.

> Why did it not print the (non-zero) value of $reply?

Because `reply` doesn't store exit status as explained before. There's actually a variable for that provided by shell already, `$?` so use that as

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

Rinse and repeat the suggestions for other statements in your script.

Good luck

Comment: @DaveKimble Yeah, it takes time getting used to the syntax in shell scripting. But eventually you'll get it with enough practice and reading answers here and on unix.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow. And you can always try Python. Syntax is nicer there and faster but you have to call external commands like `mount` via `Popen` module.  Btw, if the answer solved the problem, don't forget to mark it as accepted  ( grey checkmark ). Or leave it unmarked. It's not a requirement.

Comment: if you are using bash then in 99/100 cases, you probably want to use `[[ expression ]]` instead of the older `[ expression ` / `test` , `[[` is a safer bash builtin with more features and less weird behaviour

Comment: A bit non-standard, but I like to use `if (( $? ))` which succeeds for any non-zero (error) return. A variation on that is `rc=$?; if (( rc ))` . Then I have the actual return value to use in the script and in error messages. This is handy for commands like `mount` which can return more than one error code.

Comment: @Joe Interesting approach, flips the logic around, making if focus on non-zero exit status. I like it, might come handy in future. Thanks for sharing !

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for the feedback. I've been writing a number of bash functions with reversed return codes (0 == failure) just so I can test them this way without negations.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Sergiy's good answer, you could consider using AND and OR lists to quickly check if a command returns an exit status of zero (succeeded) or not, for example

```
command && echo "command succeeded" || echo "command failed"
```

Here's an excerpt from `man bash`:

> AND  and  OR  lists are sequences of one or more pipelines separated by
>       the `&&` and `||` control operators, respectively.  AND and  OR  lists  are
>       executed with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
>       command1 && command2
> ```
>
> command2  is  executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status
>       of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
>       command1 || command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if and only if command1 returns  a  non-zero  exit
>       status.   The  return  status of AND and OR lists is the exit status of
>       the last command executed in the list.

You could combine them, and also see the exit status if you want, with your example like:

```
sudo mount 192.168.0.2:/home/dk/NFS /home/dk/NFS && \
echo "NFS mounted OK" || echo "Mounting NFS failed: $?"
```

Comment: +1, But: That's great for use in the CLI, but you need more syntax if you need to do anything further and it's really easy to accidentally have another command run before you examine `$?` and get the subsequent command's return status. In particular, if `mount` fails, that usually means that something later is going to need to know about it.

Comment: @Joe The "if and only if" makes sure that the exit status is from the first command, but they can get complicated if you string several together in different orders. Often the whole point of these is to do something when a command fails... in that case assigning `$?` to another variable, or setting a true/false variable might help

Comment: Also, you can always use `{ }`'s to create a more complicated "command2"

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your script:

- You missed `` ` `` for `sudo mount ..` command. To execute a command, you need to put it back quotes `` `command` `` or `$(command)`. You can capture return value of the script using `$?` as well.
- If loop construct was wrong

  ```
  if [ $var -eq/-lt/-gt "string"/number ]
  then
  echo "...."
  else
  echo "..."
  fi; <=== Most users miss this.
  ```

** Edited script**

```
#!/bin/bash

reply=`sudo mount 192.168.0.2:/home/dk/NFS /home/dk/NFS`

if [ $reply -eq "0" ]
then 
echo "NFS mounted OK"
else 
echo "Mounting NFS failed: $reply"
fi;

reply=`sudo mount LABEL="60GB" /home/dk/60GB`
if[ $reply -eq "0" ]
then 
    echo "60GB mounted OK"
else 
    echo "Mounting 60GB failed: $reply"
fi;
exit 0
```

Comment: Most users miss what? The semicolon after `fi` is definitely not needed. And command substitution has been [mentioned by Sergiy](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088750/250300) already. Note that `$(command)` should be preferred to backticks.

Comment: I doubt that `mount` (or most other commands) is going to print a `0` on `stdout`. You need to be checking `$?` - the return status of the command (and saving it in a variable if you need to print or test it later). Ending with `exit 0` doesn't add anything here because it's very hard to make the `echo` command fail. If you save the return status in a variable such as `reply`, then you can `exit $reply` and let whatever called this know how it turned out.